# How to get all the x, y coordinates of touch of a drawing and send it to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin

I am developing a drawing application and I would like to take all the x, y coordinates of the drawing and send it to MainActivity. The project is divided into two classes, MainActivity responsible for managing the functionalities, and MyCanvas, responsible for the screen drawings.

[image]

MainAcitivity:

```
protected val mycanvas: MyCanvas? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    appLaunched(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
    my_canvas.mListener = this
    setBackgroundColor(config.canvasBackgroundColor)
    setColor(config.brushColor)
    defaultPath = config.lastSaveFolder
    defaultExtension = config.lastSaveExtension
    brushSize = config.brushSize

    undo.setOnClickListener { my_canvas.undo() }
    eraser.setOnClickListener { eraserClicked() }
    redo.setOnClickListener { my_canvas.redo() }

    checkIntents()
    if (!isImageCaptureIntent) {
        checkWhatsNewDialog()
    }

    val fab: View = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Here's a Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null)
                .show()
        Log.i("test", mycanvas?.mStartX.toString())
    }
}
```

and MyCanvas

```
var mCurX = 0f
var mCurY = 0f
var mStartX = 0f
var mStartY = 0f
private var mCurrBrushSize = 0f
private var mAllowZooming = true
private var mIsEraserOn = false
private var mWasMultitouch = false
private var mBackgroundColor = 0
private var mCenter: PointF? = null

private var mScaleDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
private var mScaleFactor = 1f

init {
    mPaint.apply {
        color = mPaintOptions.color
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        strokeWidth = mPaintOptions.strokeWidth
        isAntiAlias = true
    }

    mScaleDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(context, ScaleListener())
    pathsUpdated()
}

fun undo() {
    if (mPaths.isEmpty() && mLastPaths.isNotEmpty()) {
        mPaths = mLastPaths.clone() as LinkedHashMap<MyPath, PaintOptions>
        mBackgroundBitmap = mLastBackgroundBitmap
        mLastPaths.clear()
        pathsUpdated()
        invalidate()
        return
    }

    if (mPaths.isEmpty()) {
        return
    }

    val lastPath = mPaths.values.lastOrNull()
    val lastKey = mPaths.keys.lastOrNull()

    mPaths.remove(lastKey)
    if (lastPath != null && lastKey != null) {
        mUndonePaths[lastKey] = lastPath
        mListener?.toggleRedoVisibility(true)
    }
    pathsUpdated()
    invalidate()
}

fun redo() {
    if (mUndonePaths.keys.isEmpty()) {
        mListener?.toggleRedoVisibility(false)
        return
    }

    val lastKey = mUndonePaths.keys.last()
    addPath(lastKey, mUndonePaths.values.last())
    mUndonePaths.remove(lastKey)
    if (mUndonePaths.isEmpty()) {
        mListener?.toggleRedoVisibility(false)
    }
    invalidate()
}

fun toggleEraser(isEraserOn: Boolean) {
    mIsEraserOn = isEraserOn
    mPaintOptions.isEraser = isEraserOn
    invalidate()
}

fun setColor(newColor: Int) {
    mPaintOptions.color = newColor
}

fun updateBackgroundColor(newColor: Int) {
    mBackgroundColor = newColor
    setBackgroundColor(newColor)
    mBackgroundBitmap = null
}

fun setBrushSize(newBrushSize: Float) {
    mCurrBrushSize = newBrushSize
    mPaintOptions.strokeWidth = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.full_brush_size) * (newBrushSize / mScaleFactor / 100f)
}

fun setAllowZooming(allowZooming: Boolean) {
    mAllowZooming = allowZooming
}

fun getBitmap(): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}

fun drawBitmap(activity: Activity, path: Any) {
    Thread {
        val size = Point()
        activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getSize(size)
        val options = RequestOptions()
                .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
                .disallowHardwareConfig()
                .fitCenter()

        try {
            val builder = Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(path)
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(size.x, size.y)

            mBackgroundBitmap = builder.get()
            activity.runOnUiThread {
                invalidate()
            }
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            val errorMsg = String.format(activity.getString(R.string.failed_to_load_image), path)
            activity.toast(errorMsg)
        }
    }.start()
}
fun actionMove(x: Float, y: Float) {
    mPath.quadTo(mCurX, mCurY, (x + mCurX) / 2, (y + mCurY) / 2)
    mCurX = x
    mCurY = y
    Log.i("coordinates", mCurX.toString()+"\n"+mCurY.toString())
}
```

Exit the log is all coordinates the draw.

[image]

if I try to access the MyCanvas class variable it returns null .. as seen in the MainActivity class log

```
I/test: null
```

How do I get all the x, y coordinates made in the drawing of the screen in the MainActivity class?

Comment: you can use intents to send these data , like i suggest on my answer

Comment: in this drawing of the image in the question, there are several coordinates, because each line made is a set of x, y

Answer (score 1):

In your function `fun actionMove(x: Float, y: Float)` , you can send `mCurX.toString()` and `mCurY.toString()` to your mainActivity class with **Intent** , the idea here is each time there is a new coordinates x,y , they will be sent to your main class

This is how intent works :

```
// the sending class
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Destination_class.class);
intent.putExtra("mCurx", mCurX.toString());
intent.putExtra("mCury", mCurY.toString());
startActivity(intent);


// the receiving one
String mCurx = getIntent().getStringExtra("mCurx");
String mCury = getIntent().getStringExtra("mCury");
```

Comment: I think it would be better to store them all in an arraylist and send, don't you think? now i'm not sure how to do it, so the question. Because passing through an array, I'll just get the coordinates to use them in another functionality when the drawing is finished.

Comment: Yes you can send an array instead

Comment: do you know how i can do this? I don't know how I do it

Comment: There is a better idea than using an array , you can use a class that will contain as attribute all the coordinates you'll need { mcurx , mcury .... etc } , you will initializate it at the debut , and for each function that provides a coordinate you will add it to the object with a setter , at the end you will send the object with intent

Comment: @CarlosDiego marking my question will be appreciated if you're helped